# Cannot use functions and variables in DEFAULT constraint when creating a new database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a new database using the CREATE command. Here's the SQL:

> `CREATE TABLE test(
>         rok_utworzenia timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
>       );`

But it throws an error saying

> '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE )' at line 2'

It works if I change the DEFAULT constraint to a constant, but not if I try to use any function or variable. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE TABLE test( rok_utworzenia timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

From [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a
>   TIMESTAMP column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE test( rok_utworzenia timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```